# Synchronizing the data with the server if not saved automatically

Tags: java, android, database, web-services

I have developed an application that saves every call made by phone to the database. This is working just fine as as soon as call ends i fetch all the call details and run the web service for saving it and the call is saved.

**But the problem arises once there is no network connection or weak access to internet**. The calls are not saved.
I am finding a way out where I can save all the unsaved calls once every day so that I get 100% call log of phone.
 **I tried saving the table id received from server after successful log into a hashmap and then run a loop where the service will run until a log with no table id is found and a service will run in background with Alarm Manager that would run it after every 24 hours in background. This is how I did it.**

```
 public class Senddata extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    String oppurjson;
    String oppurerror = null;
    ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(Create_log.this);
    String oppurdata = "";

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // NOTE: You can call UI Element here.

        //Start Progress Dialog (Message)

        pd.setMessage("Please wait..");
        pd.show();
        pd.setCancelable(false);
        pd.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

        try {
            if (sharedpreferences.contains(user)) {
                idofuser = sharedpreferences.getString(user, "");
                // System.out.println("Id of user is"+idofuser);
            }
            // Set Request parameter
            oppurdata += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("user_id", "UTF-8") + "=" + idofuser;
            oppurdata += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("call_start", "UTF-8") + "=" + calldatechange1;
            oppurdata += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("duration", "UTF-8") + "=" + callDuration1;
            oppurdata += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("direction", "UTF-8") + "=" + dir;
            oppurdata += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("mob", "UTF-8") + "=" + ggg;

            System.out.println("data going to be saved is-----" + oppurdata);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    protected Void doInBackground(String... urls) {
        /************ Make Post Call To Web Server ***********/
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        // Send data
        try {
            // Defined URL  where to send data
            URL url = new URL(urls[0]);

            // Send POST data request

            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);

            conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
            wr.write(oppurdata);
            wr.flush();

            // Get the server response

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;


            // Read Server Response
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                // Append server response in string
                sb.append(line + " ");
            }

            // Append Server Response To Content String
            oppurjson = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            oppurerror = ex.getMessage();
        } finally {
            try {
                reader.close();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            }
        }

        /*****************************************************/
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
        // NOTE: You can call UI Element here.

        // Close progress dialog
 //            pd.dismiss();

        if (oppurerror != null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to create the call log.Try Again later", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else {    // Show Response Json On Screen (activity)
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Log created successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            String OutputData = "";

            try {
                //JSONObject  jsonRootObject = new JSONObject(oppurjson);
                JSONObject jsonRootObject = new JSONObject(oppurjson);
                JSONObject json2 = jsonRootObject.getJSONObject("jsonobj");

                callstable = json2.optString("calls_table_id").toString();
                status = json2.optString("status").toString();

                HashMap<String,String> hm=new HashMap<>();
                hm.put("key",callstable);
                System.out.println("the calls table is"+callstable +"and the status is"+status);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        Create_log.this.finish();
       moveTaskToBack(false);
    }
}
```

I have added the data to hashmap but it is returning errors there and data is not getting added every time. Please suggest me as is this the best way to achieve what I want to achieve. If yes, What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `saves every call made by phone to the database` ? 'The' database? You better introduce the setup with `to a database on the web`.

Comment: yes sorry. I meant a database on the web. SQLdatabase. Tell me what should i do to achieve this.?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you call entities have some structure when stored on the device, I would suggest you add a syncStatus field to each call entity in your database. The syncStatus could either be a value "pendingSync" or "synced". All calls should be stored as "pendingSync". Then implement a syncadapter which just uploads all the entities with a pendingSync syncStatus to your web service, and upon successful upload for each entity update it's local status to "synced". But of course you can read more on such here https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html There should be a tutorial there somewhere too.

Prelude: Note sure if you implemented an actual database for your application but I would suggest you look at the other persistence option you have on Android. I do see the sharedpreferences variable you have but that might not be the best coding practice for what you are doing. I've used an SQLite database for a similar objective. Maybe read up on all the alternative which cases are suitable for each here https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

If you are new to Android, the best thing for you to do is create a new app for each new function you are learning and explore as much of that function without being blinded by the action you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I am not using Sqlite database so using sync adapter will not be good i guess. Can uh help me with using the hashmap for storing and then syncing the data after every 24 hours.